# Can I choose which Zeds I play as?

Tags: killing-floor-2

I started experimenting with the VS Survival multiplayer mode last night with a friend, where one team plays as Zeds and the other team plays as humans.

I spawned as a Slasher and an Alpha Clot in the first couple of waves, then spawned as a Husk, and finally, a Scrake. However, when it was my friend's turn to play as the Zeds, he spawned as a Crawler a couple times, but not as a Clot variant.

Is there a way to choose which Zed I spawn as? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, 10+ hours of VS survival, there is no way to select which zed you play as. You continue to respawn as zeds as long there are zeds left in the wave and players do not currently possess that body. As you progress through the game and continue to respawn as zeds, you gradually progress through the zed tiers.

If you have played through any mode in Killing Floor 2, you have noticed that not all zed types spawn each wave. The lowest tier includes crawlers, clots, bloats and gorefasts. The middle tier includes sirens, husks, and stalkers. The last tier includes scrakes and fleshpounds. And then there is the patriarch. I don't include the patriarch in any of the tiers because there is only one in a game, so only one person gets to play as him.

You are not always going to progress when you respawn though. For example, if all of the scrakes for that wave have spawned, you will not be a scrake.